# Ruby Locales get lost with page navigation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locale

So i have different pages for different urls(locales). My problem is when i navigate from one page to the next, the default url comes up and you see the default site not the one specific for the initial url request.

So basically i initially access

```
 htttp://localhost:3000/?locale=ru
```

for the first page in my application the russian site comes up. When i navigate to the next page it goes back to

```
 htttp://localhost:3000
```

and loads this page. I have no idea why. Would anyone know?

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

I have done this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to persist the locale in your session; otherwise the information will be lost between requests, just as you've experienced. Do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController <  ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    @locale ||= params[:locale] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    I18n.locale = session[:locale] = @locale
  end

end
```

That will set `@locale` to whatever's in the params, or whatever's in the session, or what the default_locale is, and then set both the session and the I18n locale based on that.

Comment: Thanks but I also have one question. The url goes back to the default url. Is there any way in which i can change that to stay the same?